# Exit from the oracle user session when running a script

Tags: oracle, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a problem with a bash script on an Ubuntu system. I need to program a script which connects to oracle an spool some queries to text files.

Almost all of this tasks are acomplished but the script doesn't run as it should be.

To generate the connection to oracle I use the following lines inside my script:

```
su oracle
export ORACLE_SID=DB_SID
export ORACLE_HOME=[ORACLE_PATH]
export TWO_TASK=[HOSTNAME:PORT]
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
sqlplus -s usr/pass << EOF
```

In the subsequent lines I make all the spooling of the data and finally for exiting from sqlplus I use the following lines:

```
quit;
```

To diconnect from sqlplus

```
exit
```

To exit from the su oracle session

```
EOF
```

And after the EOF tag I put some other commands to be executed.

Problem is when I run my script:

```
user# sh MyScript.sh
```

Instead of doing all the tasks, the script only executes the lines to the point of the << EOF and returns to me the control of the terminal still logged as the oracle user.

```
oracle@user#
```

If I type 'exit' and press enter then the rest of the script is executed.

I need the script to execute from start to finish without this middle step but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try swapping your `exit` and `EOF`. You want everything between `<<EOF` and `EOF` to be commands to SQLPlus but the exit is a command for the shell.

Comment: Forgot to mention this MAtthew when I swap those lines then it requieres me the su password, when typing the password I have for work it says it's not the proper password and then executes only the code between the EOF points.

Comment: Does `su oracle` work for you in the shell normally (i.e. when not in a script)?

Comment: Yes, it works normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it's not neccesary to use the [su oracle] to make the export of the environment variables so I simply deleted the line:

```
su oracle
```

And the process worked like a charm.

Thanks for all who helped.